# PHP Abstract function com argumento de interface

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma função abstrata passando uma interface como argumento:

```
abstract class AbstractManagement {
   abstract public function handle(RequestInterface $request) :array;
}
```

Mas quando tento criar esse método na minha classe:

```
namespace App\Http\RequestManagement;

use App\Http\Requests\ServiceStoreAndUpdate as Request;
//ServiceStoreAndUpdate implementa RequestInterface

class ServiceStoreAndUpdate extends AbstractManagement
{
    public function handle(Request $request) :array
    {
        return $request->validated();
    }
}
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Declaration of
>   App\Http\RequestManagement\ServiceStoreAndUpdate::handle(App\Http\Requests\ServiceStoreAndUpdate
>   $request): array must be compatible with
>   App\Http\RequestManagement\AbstractManagement::handle(App\Http\Requests\RequestInterface
>   $request): array"

Não é possível passar uma interface, ou uma classe pai como argumento em uma função abstrata?

Comment: `$request->validated();` retorna o que? um boolean?

Comment: Retorna um array.